# Suppress FindBugs warning in static initializer

Tags: java, findbugs, suppress-warnings

I have a static initializer where I am creating a new `File` object. When I pass in the name to it FindBugs reports a warning due to the hard-coded absolute path. How can I suppress this warning?

```
private static final String fileName = "/tmp/m123.txt";
static {
    if (new File(fileName).exists()) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code? It sounds like it is hardcoded data... have you considered moving it into an annotation?

Comment: Hi, I have updated with my code example... The warning is of type DMI_HARDCODED_ABSOLUTE_FILENAME

Answer (score 1):

You could move this hard-coded filename to a properties file, or command line argument etc.

See this page for a tutorial on property files http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

In you want to ignore this warning though as per the page findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#commandLineOptions you can use -exclude filterFile.xml

Comment: I have already defined the filename as public static final String... isn't this enough?

Comment: Thanks... but isn't there any other way to suppress this warning?

Comment: Yes, as per the page http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#commandLineOptions you can use `-exclude filterFile.xml`

Comment: what about annotations... I am able to suppress many warnings using annotations but not this one... why?

Comment: OK, that is a different question to which I do not know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ENUM, I use ENUM to eliminate hardcoding of the strings/text both findbugs and pmd doesn't to show errors or warning.

```
public enum MyFiles {

    FILE_NAME("/kp/kp1/kp2.tx");

    private String value;

    MyFiles(String value){

        this.value = value;

    }
```

Your fileName is not uppercase, hence pmd would show error of type 1 for the same. So change it to upper case

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/m123.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I wouldn't advocate refactoring code too much to avoid warnings, but in this case you're stuck because you cannot annotate static initializers. You can move the code to a static method in another class which you may annotate with `SuppressFBWarnings`.

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/m123.txt";

    static {
        HelperClass.loadFile(FILE_NAME);
    }
}

public class HelperClass {
    @SuppressFBWarnings("DMI_HARDCODED_ABSOLUTE_FILENAME")
    public static void loadFile(String fileName) {
        if (new File(fileName).exists()) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Extracting the code may actually be enough to avoid the warning, but I've never encountered this warning before.